# Multiple loop with pagination in same page

Tags: loop, pagination, query

In my home page i have two `<section>` in which i perform two different loops on different post categories. Here the code:

```
<section>
        <ul class="loop-article">
            <?php
                $pagedArticles = ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 );
                $articles = array('post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => 3,'paged' => $pagedArticles );
                query_posts($articles); $i=0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++;
            ?>  
<!-- do stuff  -->
            <?php endwhile; global $wp_query;
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
            echo paginate_links( array('base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),'format' => '?paged=%#%','current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages) ); 
            wp_reset_query(); ?>            
        </ul>
</section>
<section>
            <ul class="loop-news">
            <?php
                $pagedNews = ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 );
                $news = array('post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'cat' => 4, 'paged' => $pagedNews );
                query_posts($news); $i=0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++;
            ?>                  
    <!-- do stuff  -->
            <?php endwhile; global $wp_query;
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
            echo paginate_links( array('base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),'format' => '?paged=%#%','current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages) ); 
            wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
</section>
```

The problem i face is that if i try to see older posts of `'.loop-article'`, pagination works on `'.loop-news'` too.

I think it depends on the same url that paginator creates for both loops:

```
www.mysite.com/page/2/
```

But i am not sure of this...is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by AJAX, [Read this](http://wordpressapi.com/2011/05/16/add-ajax-pagination-in-wordpress-blog/) tutorial which with a little modification can do what you want.

Comment: Thanks...is not a bad idea...but i am wondering if that is just a work around..